# The program does not print the values

Tags: c, string

Hello my software should print the abc but unfortunately it does not work I think the problem is related to the line 19 so if someone could tell me why this is happening I appreciate it

My code-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_ABC_LET 27

void ABC(char abc[NUM_ABC_LET]);
int main()
{
    char abcString[NUM_ABC_LET] = "";
    ABC(abcString);
    puts(abcString);
}

void ABC(char abc[NUM_ABC_LET])
{
    char letter;
    for (letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++)
    {
        strcat(abc, letter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you getting warnings about an incorrect argument to `strcat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the function `stdcat()` expects a null terminated string as second argument.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_ABC_LET 27

void ABC(char abc[NUM_ABC_LET]);

int main()
{
    char abcString[NUM_ABC_LET] = "";
    ABC(abcString);
    puts(abcString);
}

void ABC(char abc[NUM_ABC_LET])
{
    char letterStr[2];
    strcpy(letterStr, "x");
    for (char letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++) {
        letterStr[0] = letter;
        strcat(abc, letterStr);
    }
}
```

Much simpler is this solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_ABC_LET 27

void ABC(char abc[NUM_ABC_LET]);

int main()
{
    char abcString[NUM_ABC_LET];
    ABC(abcString);
    puts(abcString);
}

void ABC(char abc[NUM_ABC_LET])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
        abc[i] = 'a'+i;
    }
    // Add the terminating null character.
    abc[NUM_ABC_LET-1] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're just writing to a copy of the string you're passing to the function. Try this:

```
void ABC(char *abc)
{
    int n=0;
    char letter;
    for (letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; ++letter, ++n)
    {
        abc[n] = letter;
    }
    abc[n] = '\0';
}
```

This way, you don't write to a copy of your string, you actually write to the string itself.

Comment: You don't see a problem with calling strcat with a *char* source ? As far as that goes, are you familiar with [Shlemiel the Painter's Algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html)? (obviously the OP is *not*). In a word, *ouch*.

Comment: @WhozCraig nope, never heard of it.

Comment: the article I linked is written by one of the founders of this site =P. And thanks for fixing the code (cough... terminate the string... cough).

Comment: @WhozCraig Awesome, I'll give it a look.

Comment: @WhozCraig I just looked over it, and yeah I'm familiar with it, I just didn't want to do too much pointer arithmetic, since the OP doesn't seem to have a great understanding of pointers yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable warnings in your compiler (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror`) it will tell you the problem straight away: you are using strcat in a nonsensical way.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of [srtcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) should be a `char *`.

```
void ABC(char abc[NUM_ABC_LET])
{
    char letter[2]="a";
    for (; *letter <= 'z'; (*letter)++)
    {
        strcat(abc, letter);
    }
}
```